# Getting response by opening a browser in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0, onedrive

I am using ruby -v 2.1.5  .

I am trying to use the onedrive API to authorize my user(oAuth2) in my web app.

I am following the steps specified in https://github.com/ronyv89/skydrive/blob/master/README.md

I got the auth_url by using the following steps,

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'skydrive'

class LivePartnerApp 

client_id = "MY_CLIENT_ID"
client_secret = "MY_CLIENT_SECRET"
call_back_url = "http://sample.samplewebsite.com/"


oauth_client = Skydrive::Oauth::Client.new(client_id, client_secret, call_back_url, "wl.skydrive_update,wl.offline_access")
puts "oauth_client --- #{oauth_client.inspect}"
auth_url = oauth_client.authorize_url
puts "auth_url - #{auth_url.inspect}"

response = system("open", "#{auth_url}")

puts "response #{response.inspect}"
end
```

when I try to run this file. I am getting proper response for oauth_client and auth_url.

also,

```
 response = system("open", "#{auth_url}")
```

properly opening my browser and redirecting to my redirect_url.

But my problem is,
  After this redirection step I was bound to get a **code** using which I should obtain a **access token**.

But the **response** variable above is returning only either **true** or **false** depending on the success of the redirection.

Can anybody suggest a way to get this code programmatically in ruby so that I can use it to obtain access token?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're calling the command line (ie shell) with `system`:  `system` doesn't return the command line results, it just returns true or false.  Have a look at

http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/03/ruby-shell-commands.html

I usually use backticks, eg

```
response = `open #{auth_url}`
```

Comment: I tried using the above code. but ruby considering **auth_url** as a file name and showing **No such file or directory** error.

Comment: Ah, i assumed "open" was a command for the command line.  I think your problem might be that you are loading loads of skydive stuff in your ruby runtime, and then you do a shell command with "system".  The environment that the system command runs in is just your basic command line environment - it won't have all of the skydive stuff.  Shouldn't you be using some method of your oauth_client object instead of doing a system call?